# How can I create a slider in Power BI to adjust a percentage in a dashboard?

Tags: excel, dataframe, powerbi, data-analysis, powerquery

I have a column of data with percentages that's used in a calculation for revenue. However I want to include a slider (doesnt have to be a slider though, the visual isn't the concern here) in my dashboard for another column that adjusts all of the percentages by say 5%. So it would look something like this:

Slider: +5%

| Original % | Revenue | Adjusted % | Adjusted Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50% | 100,000 | 55% | new revenue |
| 45% | 60,000 | 50% | new revenue |

Any idea how to do this when the original percentage is being used in a long string of transformations and calculations to get the revenue? I'm just not sure how to get it to replicate all of that.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/

Comment: Take a look at [What-if parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if).